# RAETH ethernet switch unable to receive packets/DHCP

Tags: router, dns, routing, dhcp, vlan

I've been working on a common RALINK platform (MT7621) and I've had some trouble getting the ethernet ports to receive packets, which I assume is the main reason they cannot receive an IP from the DHCP server (DNSMASQ) on the router. There is nothing wrong with the ports, and the ethernet driver correctly reports the Link going Up/Down when the cable is inserted/removed.

System Information:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# uname -a
Linux DD-WRT 4.14.19 #946 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 14 11:25:30 MST 2018 mips GNU/Linux
```

There are three items connected to the bridge interface 'br0': two wireless radios, and the gigabit ethernet switch:

LAN(eth2)/WAN(eth3) interfaces:

```
eth2: flags=4163 < UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
      inet6 fe80::7a32:xxxx:xxxx:96fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
      ether 78:32:xx:xx:96:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
      RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
      TX packets 102  bytes 7444 (7.2 KiB)
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
      device interrupt 3  

eth3: flags=4931 < UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
      inet6 fe80::7a32:xxxx:xxxx:9700  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
      ether 78:32:xx:xx:97:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
      RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
      TX packets 13  bytes 1006 (1006.0 B)
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

bridge:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.7832xxxx96fd       no              eth2
                                                        ra0
                                                        rai0
```

edit: I should mention there is no modem connected to the WAN port (i.e. I am just trying to get local DHCP). the content of 'route', /etc/resolv.conf, and /etc/hosts are as follows:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0

root@DD-WRT:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.1     DD-WRT
root@DD-WRT:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Neither wireless interface has any issue assigning IPs to connected devices, leading me to believe this is related to some changes between Kernel 3.x and 4.x with respect to routing

Below I have provided as much information I can regarding this problem. I will also mention the relevant features for this specific gigabit switch (MT7530) are enabled (NET_DSA_MT7530, CONFIG_BRIDGE_VLAN_FILTERING, CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER)

To ensure the problem wasn't related to iptables, I have compiled the kernel without any NAT/IPTABLES/NF features and I still have this problem, which leads me to believe I am missing something with respect to the "vlan tags". I did not deviate from RALINK's configuration script.

```
root@DD-WRT:~# cat /proc/net/vlan/config 
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
eth2.1         | 1  | eth2
eth2.2         | 2  | eth2
eth2.3         | 3  | eth2
eth2.4         | 4  | eth2
```

where each vlan has the same configuration, as follows:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# cat /proc/net/vlan/eth2.1
eth2.1  VID: 1   REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1001
     total frames received            0
      total bytes received            0
  Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

  total frames transmitted           14     
  total bytes transmitted          1076
Device: eth2
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:1  2:2  3:3  4:4  5:5  6:6 7:7
 EGRESS priority mappings: 0:0 1:1 2:2 3:3 4:4 5:5 6:6 7:7
```

An additional note: it does not matter whether I add the vlans (eth2.1,eth2.2,eth2.3,eth2.4) to the bridge or not, the behaviour does not change (which, I suspect, is the expected behaviour).

here's some additional information for people familiar with RALINK's switch program, just to provide an idea of how the switch is setup:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# switch dump
hash  port(0:6)   fid   vid  age   mac-address     filter my_mac
724:   ---1 ----    0     4  146  406c8xxxx9d2     -     -
found the last entry 1 (not ready)

root@DD-WRT:~# cat /proc/mt7621/port_status 
Port0: LinkDown
Port1: LinkDown
Port2: LinkDown
Port3: LinkUp
Port4: LinkDown
```

the device reported on vid 4 is connected to ethernet port 3 (fourth port, goes 0,1,2,3), which is correct when inspecting the vlan mapping below (eth2.4 is vid 4, the vlan for port 3 on the switch):

```
root@DD-WRT:~# switch vlan dump
  vid  fid  portmap    s-tag
    1    0  1-----11       0
    2    0  -1----11       0
    3    0  --1---11       0
    4    0  ---1--11       0
    5    0  ----11--       0
    6    0  invalid
    7    0  invalid
    8    0  invalid
    9    0  invalid
   10    0  invalid
   11    0  invalid
   12    0  invalid
   13    0  invalid
   14    0  invalid  
   15    0  invalid
   16    0  invalid
```

If anyone would like additional information regarding the kernel configuration and whatnot, I'll be happy to provide it. As it is, I do not know what is missing. I concede I am not an expert when it comes to networking (though I do have some expertise in the computing area, just not this one), so I could be missing a simple "echo 1 > /proc/net/" or something like that.

To me, everything looks correct. I just have no idea why packets are not being received!

edit (FEB 22 2018): Here is some ethool output. if it helps, the LAN port is supposed to be "TRGMII" (not sure if that is reflected in ethtool, it may not be), and the wan port "RGMII":

```
root@DD-WRT:~# ethtool eth2
Settings for eth2:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full     
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Link detected: no
```

the "wan":

```
Settings for eth3:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 10Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 4
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Link detected: no
```

and the VLANs:

```
Settings for eth2.1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 10Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Link detected: yes
```

I will add more information as I play with ethtool (new to this. sorry!)

Comment: What's the make/model of the dd-wrt router supplying DHCP? Keep in mind some models have the logical ports backwards from the physical. I.e in the config configuring port 0 may actually be physical port 4. Which can add alot of confusion.

Comment: Hi Tim, all of this is on the same router, the D-LINK DIR 882 A1. Yeah, I am aware that the RAETH routers can potentially have their GDMA ports swapped. However, I do not think this model is affected by that because the GPL code's ethernet driver does not have the GDMA_SWAP option (unlike the ASUSWRT variants), and they do update the code in the driver between releases (most recent version is here: https://dlink-gpl.s3.amazonaws.com/GPL1700180/DIR882A1_V1.01B02.tar.gz) WAN_AT_P4 corresponds to eth3, and I think it's correct (feel free to ask for more information).